# Redirecting from javascript with css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a win32 amateur coder and a newbie web programmer. For my personal project I am trying to modify a to-do list code in codepen.

http://codepen.io/arjancodes/pen/Bahkb

Here is my code:

```
// get rid of default value in input box
$('input[name=toDoItem]').focus(function() {
  $(this).val('');
})

$('#add').click(function() {

  var $input = $('input[name=toDoItem]').val();

  if ($input.length > 0) {
    $('#list').append('<li class=' + 'close' + '>' + $input + '</li>');
  } else {
    alert("We'd all love to do nothing.");
  }

  // reset input box to no text
  $('input[name=toDoItem]').val('');
});

// remove list item
$('#list').on('click', '.close', function() {
  $(this).hide('2000', function() {
     $(this).remove();
  });

});
```

In this to do list project, when clicking on "x" button, it deletes the row. But when I click to text, it also deletes. What I am going to do, is to separate delete button and text. User will write a link to input box and add it to list. After that user will click to text and the page will redirect to the link. I am hoping someone can show me the right direction, I am not asking to write all the code for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start: [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPBzLX).

If you want to have the delete button and text separated, they should be separate elements. For example:

```
<li class='item'>Do Stuff <i class='close'></i></li>
```

The CSS is updated to float the `<i>` to the right, and apply the `:after` button styling to it.
The JS is updated to match the `.close` and remove the parent/ancestor `.item`:

```
$('#list .item .close').on('click', function() { ... ; return false; } );
```

The `return false` is there so that clicking the `.close` does not 'bubble' the event and invoke this new handler on the `.item`:

```
$('#list').on('click', '.item', redirect_function);
```

The `redirect_function` is not a closure, because it's re-used in the `#add` event handler:

```
$('#list').append("<li class='item'>" + $input + "<i class='close'></i></li>")
```

As for redirecting to another URL, you can manipulate `window.location`. But, since the Todo List is purely client side, changes are not persisted.

If you want to store the TODO lists on a server, you would have to communicate the changes to the server. Classically this is done using something like:

```
<form method='post'>
  <ul>
    <li><input type='text' name='item[]' value='Stuff to do'/></li>
    <li><input type='text' name='item[]' value='....'/></li>
  </ul>
  <button type='submit' name='action' value='save-todo-list'>Save</button>
</form>
```

On the server-side, you would have a script that removes all todo list items for the authenticated user from a database, and insert the `POST`ed items.

Alternatively, you can use AJAX. For instance, the 'delete item' handler could be

```
$('#list').on('click',  '.item .close', function() {
  $.ajax( {
     method: 'POST',
     url: "/api/todo/item/delete",
     data: ...
  }
} );
```

There's [lots of resources on the matter](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=todo+list+php+mysql).

Comment: Perhaps use a real `a href` for the text?

Comment: That's definitely the way I would go, but I'm unclear as to what `href`'s value should be..

Comment: Thanks Kenney. That is a very clear starting point. It is obvious that i should improve my "element" subject. You added alert("text") when clicking the text. How about posting the text which is clicked to a string?

Comment: I updated the codepen. Typically, in event handlers, `this` is the element where the event originated. You can then use `this.textContent` for example. Out of curiosity, how are you planning to store the todo list, so that it's persistent?

Comment: as an alternative to the javascript redirect URL function, you can substitute this line: `$('#list').append("<li class='item'>" + $input + "<i class='close'></i></li>")` for this one: `$('#list').append("<li class='item'><a href=http://" + $input + " target=_blank>" + $input + "</a><i class='close'></i></li>")` then switch 'type yo stuff here' for 'enter your url here'. So the user write something like 'www.google.com' and well done.

Comment: Thanks Kenney and Leandro. I did not realize "this" element and textContent like this. I need to study w3schools for element. To store data is also problematic for me, i searched for websql on codepen. JSON Data also seems an alternative but i have to learn first. Leandro, your solution takes the progress further, i definitely use this solution.

Comment: You could use [Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp); otherwise you would have to set up a server and store the data there (something like [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29)).

Comment: I like Local Storage but i think i need to setup a server. Multiple users will use the page. What is your opinion about a very simple storage system. JSON Data? Or classic mysql db?

Comment: That all depends on how experienced you are with them and what data you are going to store. The simplest is to store one TODO list per user per file. You will want to authenticate your users, so you need a password mechanism. What server-side scripting/programming language are you going to use?

Comment: I prefer something with sql. ı have an mysql authentication system for users. Perhaps, i shall stick to that solution. I need to push all item elements to mysql table and get them back from db when loading the page.

Comment: If you already have a RDBMS for authentication then I'd stick to that - it's very flexible, and a sound basis for extension. Besides a `foreach ( $db->q( "SELECT * FROM todo WHERE user_id = ?", [ $_SESSION['user_id'] ] ) as $item ) echo "<li class='item'>$item->text<i class='close'></i></li>";` on page load (assuming PHP); you'll also need `jQuery.ajax` to signal when items are added and deleted. [A search like this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=todo+list+php+mysql) should help.

Comment: Wow Kenney. You are amazing. I will right away try that line. When adding and deleting items, is it not enough to add/delete with sql? Will JQuery.ajax make it easier?

Comment: I found this tutorial from your link : http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/ajax-todo-list-jquery-php-mysql-css/ I think i have to examine this deeply and learn how to use sql+ajax. Thank you very uch for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a structure like this:

```
<li>
    ToDo text
    <div class="close"><div>
</li>
```